# How to change base_url of other stores?

Tags: magento-1.8, database, importexport, base-url

I exported a live database from a magento installation with 2 websites and 3 different stores and imported it on another magento installation.

I already changed the base_url of the main store, but how can I change the base_url of the other stores as well? They are still the same as on live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to go to the BO :

> System > Configuration > General > Web > Secure / Unsecure

To change base URL for each websites / store ?